# Centering Navigation buttons for my website

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?products">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

That is the list that has the things in it.

```
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    color: white;
}
```

Those are the CSS things it currently has, I can't seem to make them be centered. I've looked around for about an hour, but I'm pretty much not having any luck with my current skill in this field.

Comment: floating-left is not going to center anything. Keep looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is a good way to make things go where you want.

```
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

You want to make the `<li>`'s line up and sit in the center. First you need to grab their parent (the `<ul>`) and tell it to use Flexbox.

Flex direction can be row or column. You want them to line up in a row.

Once they're lined up, justify them in the center.

The margin on the `<li>` itself just keeps them from overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `float:` css style directly moves the content to its set side. To center an element, use `auto` set for your margins or padding. `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` will center an element within it's container by having the same amount of margin or padding on both sides.

a quicker way to do this is `margin: y-margins auto;` the first value is your `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` values, the second value is your left and right.

to center text within its container, such as a `<p>` tag, use `text-align: center;`

Comment: Ok great! To move everything on line, change your `<li>` tags, or your `<a>` tag styles to `display: inline;` If your `<li>` tags have auto left and right margins, remove them and keep `text-align: center;`